# How can I use LINQ with dynamic? Generics?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, dynamic

I have this piece of code:

```
public void RepeaterListato_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (listType == "pages")
    {
        var item = (Pagina)e.Item.DataItem;
        BuildFoto(e, item, IDCategoriaImmaginiPacchettoOfferta);
    }
    else if (listType == "schede")
    {
        var item = (Scheda)e.Item.DataItem;
        BuildFoto(e, item, IDCategoriaImmaginiPacchettoOfferta);
    }
    else if (listType == "news")
    {
        var item = (New)e.Item.DataItem;
        BuildFoto(e, item, IDCategoriaImmaginiPacchettoOfferta);
    }
}

private void BuildFoto(RepeaterItemEventArgs e, dynamic item, string id)
{
    var immagine = item.Immagini.Cast<Allegato>().Where(p => p.Categoria == id).FirstOrDefault();
    if (immagine != null)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

so, due to the type of `listType` (resolved at `Page_Load`), the `item` changes, so I use `dynamic`. But LINQ doesn't works with `Cast` and `Where` on dynamically dispatched opertions.

Is there a workaround? Should I use `Generics` in your opinions? Best approches?

Comment: Could you provide a small (and complete) console app showing the issue, and share that with us? That would allow us to repro the issue quickly and give you some options for resolving it.

Comment: Do Pagina, Scheda and New inherit from a common interface/base class with Immagini as property? (if true, the item parameter can be of that type and you don't need dynamic)

Comment: They all inherit from a class called `BrObject`. But within `BrObject` there isn't `Immagini` as property.

Comment: @markzzz Can you add an interface with an Immagini property and make them implement it?

Comment: @vc74: nope. They become from DLL that I can't edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't have access to the source code of Pagina, Scheda and New, you don't have many options

One is to:

```
public void RepeaterListato_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    IEnumerable<Immagini> immagini = null;

    switch (listType)
    {
      case "pages":
        immagini = ((Pagina)e.Item.DataItem).Immagini;
        break;

      case "schede":
        immagini = ((Scheda)e.Item.DataItem).Immagini;
        break;

      case "news":
        immagini = ((New)e.Item.DataItem).Immagini;
        break;
    }

    if (immagini != null)
    {
      BuildFoto(e, immagini, IDCategoriaImmaginiPacchettoOfferta);
    }
}

private void BuildFoto(RepeaterItemEventArgs e, IEnumerable<Immagini> immagini, string id)
{
    var immagine = immagini.Cast<Allegato>().Where(p => p.Categoria == id).FirstOrDefault();
    if (immagine != null)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Another option is to use reflection to get the immagini collection instance

And yet another option is to create wrapper classes:

```
public interface IImmaginiContainer
{
  IEnumerable<IImmagine> Immagini { get; }
}

public class NewWrapper : IImmaginiContainer
{
  public NewWrapper(New source)
  {
    _source = source;
  }
  private readonly New _source;

  public IEnumerable<IImmagine> Immagini => _source.Immagini;
}

// Create a similar class for Scheda and Pagina

private void BuildFoto(RepeaterItemEventArgs e, IImaginiContainer item, string id)
{
    var immagine = item.Immagini.Cast<Allegato>().Where(p => p.Categoria == id).FirstOrDefault();
    if (immagine != null)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: And using Generics? Can't help?

Comment: @markzzz You won't be able to use generics if the 3 classes don't inherit from a common interface/base class, if they did you could use generic a constraint in BuildFoto

Comment: @markzzz You could also build wrapper classes inheriting from a common ancestor with an Immagini property

Comment: Can you give to me an example of this last approch please?